# How do I terminate a SignalR stream in TypeScript without losing the connection?

Tags: c#, typescript, signalr

I want to be able to control the connection of a stream in SignalR, but I'm not sure how to do this. Currently my server side code is as follows:

```
public ChannelReader<int> MyStream(int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();
    // ... Doing some stuff
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

Besides that I'm using the channel object to write to as well. My client side code is as follows:

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(url, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();

const stream = connection.stream('MyStream', 1000);
```

Now the stream is of type `IStreamResult`, but it only has a method `.subscribe()`.
I want to be able to control whether the stream is active or not. The Hub connection has the methods `.on()` and `.off()` which can be controlled to manually register/unregister handlers. I want a similar thing for the `.stream()` method.

I only want to be able to connect and disconnect from this specific stream while the Hub maintains its overall connection. Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?